# "Select a flow of type Flow"

Tags: visual-workflow

I have created the current flow

[image: Flow Detail]

The only step it has is running an apex class.

I am trying to add this flow to a login flow, and I am receiving the following error:

[image: Select a flow of type Flow]

Why do I get this error? How do I fix it? There is no such type as "Flow" when I create it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Salesforce Security Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_login_flow_create.htm) states that you must use a Screen Flow (as opposed to this Autolaunched Flow) as part of your login flow. That appears to be what's preventing you from selecting the Flow, although the error message doesn't make this very clear.